# Why might Ubuntu be slow for me while using Wubi?

Tags: wubi

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu in general. I just Wubi installed Ubuntu 11.04 w/Windows 7 on my Lenovo laptop - Intel i7 Quad Core 2Ghz, 4Gb ram, etc. etc... and for some reason Ubuntu is very laggy and slow.

When I'm switching between programs (Chromium, folders, software center, etc..) it doesn't run as smoothly as Windows 7 (I have no more than 3 programs/windows up at a time...). I don't think it's my system requirements because Linux OSs are known to use low system resources. I installed it using Wubi - should I do a reinstall? I've already done all the recommended updates..

Comment: Wubi installs Ubuntu on a NTFS partition as a FILE, it's as it implies just a way to try Ubuntu. To get Ubuntu to really be as fast as it should on your hardware you should put it on its own partition.

Comment: For example when you were installing the Wubi, it asks for the disk space like 17GB or 20GB and so on... So is it because of if you choose like very low? I choose 18GB and also find Wubi a little laggy sometimes.... Any comments?

Comment: @UriHerrera - +1 I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.04 is still a bit buggy. It should pick up after a few more updates. Or try installing Unity 2D from the Software Center. This will definitely give you a noticeable boost of performance. It is a lot lighter on resources than the default Unity. :)

Answer (score 0):

The new Unity launcher in Ubuntu 11.4 isn't as fast as the system used to be. Try selecting the "Ubuntu Classic" option on the login page. It should fee a bit more snappy.

Wubi shouldn't cause any significant performance issues. I used Wubi for about 18 months without any problems. One thing to check is that you gave the system enough disk space. Really Ubuntu should be equally fast, if not a little sharper than windows even on old low spec machines.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 11.04 was the first with Unity.  By now it's a more mature environment and many small things have been fixed or improved, so that it's much faster now than in the past.  I think if you try it now (12.04 is due to be released tomorrow) you'll find it much snappier and more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the proprietary NVIDIA drivers make sure your xorg.conf file contains the `RenderAccel` and `UseEvents` directives.

**WARNING:** Editing this file directly can be dangerous. Make sure you follow the instructions exactly.

First backup your origional xorg.conf file and then edit the existing copy. To do this:

Open a terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and type:

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Then scroll down until you find Section "Device". If this section doesn't already contain the following statements, add them:

```
Option    "RenderAccel" "on"
Option    "UseEvents" "True"
```

Then hit `Ctrl+X` then press `Y` and `Enter` to save. Then restart your machine and let us know if this helped.